# Re-render React Compontents when changing global variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

I try to migrate an old AngularJS 1 application to React and encountered a whole bunch of problems... but the greatest of them all is getting React to re-render its components. Maybe someone has a good idea for my specific problem.

## Current situation

My application consists of a very huge rule-based calculation algorithm. Imagine a hundred switches and when you switch one it starts calculating and checking rules and after that prices are displayed and other switches may be disabled. When the disabled switches were switched on before being disabled even more rules are checked and so on...

The storage of all data and states is 100% in native global variables and arrays.

In AngularJS there was a huge scope around all switches. The switches were hooked to the global storage variables via Angular and the corresponding hooks like "ng-click" or "ng-checked".

## React migration

Now in React I start to replace the switches with React Compontents. But because I dont want to re-write the storage-mechanism I try to link the Components to the corresponding global variables.
The problem ist that these Components dont re-render after a global variable is changed (well how sould they know?).

I read a lot about React and re-rendering and my conclusion ist that the automatic re-rendering only works with props or states, which were altered inside the compontent.
Another option is to use Flux or to create an own listener-based access to the global storage by wrapping them in getter/setters but sadly that is impossible because of the size of the application and the fact that the logic and ui functions are strictly seperated with the logic functions only consisting of native JS to process it via Java Nashorn.

## Conclusion

Now I only see 2 options

- re-render all Container by force after finishing all calculations (which is discouraged like EVERYWHERE)
- use another more AngularJS like framework like vue.js (at least at first glance)

Maybe anyone here knows another way to hook global variables into the React Components...

Answer (score 1):

You can make a special Flux-based data layer in Redux (for example) and connect it to your difficult data layer through redux-observable (for example).

React <–> Redux <–> Data-layer

This will help to use all React features and not to re-render all UI on every click.

Use your data-layer just like REST api, or web-socket connection. Redux state can be equal to data-layer state, or more compact, or more React-connectable, it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think I see want your point is... but even if I hide the data layer behind a Redux-based access-layer I still have the problem that the logic which sets and reads the global variables still only can be native JS.

So I could read the global variables with React and Redux but when I set them I can only use native JS with the basic global variables so Redux will not be informed about changes, right?

Comment: Does your native JS logic have any kind of lifecycle events?
If it does, then you can call your data->redux layer every time data changes by native JS logic. Then dataToRedux layer will update redux state again.

Comment: Yes it has lifecycle events but if Iam going to manually use them to update the Redux-layer wouldnt it be easier to just force the React Components to update? As far as I have read Flux or Redux (I currently have no practical experience in both technologies) come with a huge boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

Use [redux](https://redux.js.org/). Redux is an open-source JavaScript library for managing application state.

Comment: Unfortunately thats impossible because of the size of the project and the prerequisite that all logic has to be coded in native JS, like I said in my question.